# Mysql discard LSB of decimal part of float if it is zero

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, precision, rounding

I have a mysql float field x. If I insert a value from PHP script `21.10` it saves as `21.1` .But my system treat `21.10` and `21.1` are different. So How can I prevent mysql from discarding last zero bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field in MySQL table should be of type Decimal (X,Y) where X is total digits and Y is the number of those digits that should be on the fractional side.

Example of what you need

DECIMAL(10, 2) has 8 digits onthe integer part and 2 digits on the fractional part.

Comment: Where the "length" *includes* the number of places after the decimal point. e.g., "5,2" allows 3 digits to the left and 2 to the right.